# Best way to handle hundreads of simultaneous update request in PHP-MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-performance, sql-update

I am receiving 100s of simultaneous row update request on a single table within 5-10 seconds, it causes problem, It is not actually updating the row and also not giving any error in `mysql_query($query)` response.

Please suggest what can be the cause of this and how can I solve this?

Table has something around 200k records in it. It might be one of the problem.

Comment: "not giving any error" - how are you catching errors in your code?

Comment: 100 updates in 10 seconds, 10 updates per second is not a big problem for a properly configured database. Since we have no idea *how* your database is configured or what your code does, we can't really answer what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @sandradev I am just checking $response = mysql_query($query); If $response is false, it is error.

Comment: @deceze We have a id transactionId and a index set on that table. just updating with query "update status = 1 where transactionId = '$transactionId' and someother=value;"

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

Check your storage engine configuration. It sounds like you're not actually performing 'too many' inserts, but switching to an engine better suited to lots of inserts/updates might help if you're on a strained server (like a cheap shared host):

[Comparing InnoDB to MyISAM Performance](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/comparing_innodb_to_myisam_performance)

Other potential solutions which may/may-not work for your particular case:

1) Reduce number of indexes on the table being updated, to increase the speed of updates/inserts.

2) Cache the incoming edits to a smaller table (with no indexes), then sync them periodically.

3) Consolidate inserts into a single query (though this sounds like it won't work for you) inserting them all to an in-memory temp table then INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... to make a single transaction against the target table.

Comment: We have innoDB engine already.

Comment: Good link. Though, assuming he's using the latest and greatest, it'd be up to date. And when I tested some stuff, the default engine was InnoDB. Least it was for me.